# boto3 lambda invoke function with non-json payload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I want to send string payload and **not a JSON**.
Error from boto3:

> Payload (bytes or seekable file-like object) -- JSON that you want to
>   provide to your Lambda function as input.

Example:
`client.invoke(
         FunctionName='foo',
         LogType='Tail',
         Payload="/bin/ls")`

Comment: And you can't even use `Payload='"/bin/ls"'` (note quotes)?

Comment: The documentation indicates that it should be JSON. Is it a problem for you to send it as a JSON string?